# Spring Servlet Filter causing browser connection to be reset

Tags: spring, firefox, proxy, servlet-filters

I have a Spring web app that (for the time being) only has a single servlet filter (no controllers/methods, etc.) that is configured to intercept all requests:

```
// Groovy pseudo-code, but that shouldn't matter, all the logic is there
// and we know it works (no compiler errors) because I can go to localhost:8080
// in a browser and see it.
@Override
void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    println 'I am being invoked to filter the response!'

    HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = response as HttpServletResponse
    String htmlResponse = """
    <html>
    <head><title>Hello!</title></head>
    <body>
        Hello from filter land!
    </body>
    </html>
    """

    httpServletResponse.writer.write(htmlResponse)
    httpServletResponse.writer.flush()
}
```

When I start the app and point my browser to `http://localhost:8080`, I get the expected HTML (a message that reads "*Hello from filter land!*"). I also see the `println` show up in my console output.

I then tune my browser (FireFox) to use this proxy for all HTTP traffic by going to `Preferences >> Network` and using these configs:

[image]

I hit `OK` and then go to `http://example.com` and get a "*The connection was reset*" error. In the `Web Developer >> Network` tool, there isn't much info, either. Just basically shows a bad connection:

[image]

It's also important to note that I'm not seeing the `println` print to console output when I go to `http://example.com` (or any other HTTP site) via FireFox. So clearly the browser doesn't seem to be "hitting" the filter correctly.

Any ideas as to why my servlet filter is working against `http://localhost:8080`, but not when my browser is proxied to use it? Trying to first rule out if its an app-layer issue with how I'm using servlet filters and/or Spring.

Comment: Where exactly did you learn to use filters like this? I have never seen a "Hello World" filter like this in any self-respected learning resource. A filter is not a HTTP endpoint. Your filter is basically waiting on an instruction in order to continue the request to the desired HTTP endpoint (e.g. servlet instance, JSP file, HTML file, etc). Use a HTTP servlet instead. By the way, neither servlets nor filters have anything to do with Spring. If you prefer Spring over Java EE, just use a Spring controller instead of a HTTP servlet.

Comment: I created the exact same proxy filter and ran it with the same Firefox proxy setting, and I don't get the error you're seeing in Firefox, Chrome or Safari when I go to example.com. I'm using the Spring CLI app to test the groovy filter as the only @Component of a Spring Boot app. What are you using for an app server? The fact that it's not printing to the console tells me that the problem is probably not in the app code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run a web proxy, before you can set proxy. One like this http://squidman.net/squidman/